# Traversing a BST holding custom objects

Tags: java, class, binary-search-tree

I apologize if this is a dumb or incomplete question. I am fairly new to java and OOP in general and I have a project that requires me to use a BST to store student data records.

I have created a Student class that holds the variables relevant for a student record. I have also created a generic BST class.

My question is, how can I search through this BST for students by name? When I wrote the code for this BST, it was in the context of using it for integers or Strings, so I could easily use the integer or String being held in the BST as the "key" in the parameter for the get method that I wrote.

However, with a custom student class, the first and last name are stored as variables in the field of the class. The object being stored is a student though, and I don't know how to reference a specific student object in the parameter for the get method for the tree.

Below is the find (get) method I have.

```
/**
 * Internal method to find an item in a subtree.
 *
 * @param x
 *            is item to search for.
 * @param node
 *            the node that roots the tree.
 * @return node containing the matched item.
 */
private Node<T> find(T x, Node<T> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null; // Not found
    }
    else if (x.compareTo(node.getElement()) < 0) {
        // Search in the left subtree
        return find(x, node.getLeft());
    }
    else if (x.compareTo(node.getElement()) > 0) {
        // Search in the right subtree
        return find(x, node.getRight());
    }
    else {
        return node; // Match
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, though I don't know if its a "good" one; The project specs require me to keep my BST generic. I implemented comparable with my BST, and also had my student class implement comparable. In my student class, I wrote a method that compares a student to another student by last name, then by first name.

I created a "section" class that extends a BST of type student. In my section class, I wrote a custom search method which creates a new student object based on the first and last name strings passed in the custom search method, and then I pass that new student into my generic BST search method which uses the node's (in this case student's) compareTo method to traverse the BST.

Comment: Study the `java.util.Comparator` interface and how it can be used to create custom comparisons for any class.

Comment: @JimGarrison hello, changing class `Node<T>` to `Node<T extends Comparable<T>>` and define class `Student` as `class Student implements Comparable<Student>` could solve the problem or there are pitfalls in this approach?

Comment: @dariosicily Well one pitfall I have just ran into is that I can only sort or search based on one attribute, and that is name, since the compareTo method is just one method which can be used with the comparable interface.

I think with the comparator interface (and i have not used it yet so i am unsure) I can begin to search by more than one attribute, say by student ID, or grade, etc etc.

Hopefully JimGarrison can provide some input on this.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is adding an aditional attribute in your Node class:

```
public class Node<T> {

Node<T> right;
Node<T> left;
Student st;
}
```

Generate getters and setters:

```
public Node<T> getRight() {
    return right;
}
public void setRight(Node<T> right) {
    this.right = right;
}
public Node<T> getLeft() {
    return left;
}
public void setLeft(Node<T> left) {
    this.left = left;
}
public Student getStudent() {
    return st;
}
public void setStudent(Alumno st) {
    this.st = st;
}
```

Assuming that your Student class has the variable `name` as String, it could be:

```
    private Node<Student> find(Student x, Node<Student> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null; // Not found
    } else if (x.name.compareTo(node.getLeft().getStudent().name) < 0) {
        // Search in the left subtree
        return find(x, node.getLeft());
    } else if (x.name.compareTo(node.getRight().getStudent().name) > 0) {
        // Search in the right subtree
        return find(x, node.getRight());
    } else {
        return node; // Match
    }
}
```

The method `compareTo` only accepts Strings, so, you are comparing the name of Student (`x.name`) from your argument of your `find` method with a specific name of a Student contained in your Node `Node<Student> node`. retrieved from a right or left node `node.getLeft().getStudent().name`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I thought about doing this originally but the specs of my project say to ensure that the BST and the node remain generic, that is, know nothing about the student class and vice-versa